# AttributeError: module 'bs4.element' has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a simple web **scraper** to capture different dialects. The code is below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element
import pandas as pd
import requests


capture = requests.get('http://wiwords.com/dictionary/').text
#print(capture)
results = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(capture, 'lxml')
for words in soup.find('div', class_= 'panel-body'):
    extracted = element.find('h4') # Line that causes the error
    if extracted not in results:
        results.append(extracted.text)
```

however when I run it , I get an error like " AttributeError: module 'bs4.element' has no attribute 'find' ." I saw a similar problem when search for solutions on another forum there weren't any valid answer. Any ideas as to what I could of possibly done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't import element from library its a module not an HTML tag element.
- you can use find_all() function to find all elements. find() find the first
  PageElement that matches the given criteria.
- You can correct your code by replace `element` with `words` variable.
  replace `extracted = element.find('h4')` with `extracted = words.find('h4')`
- Also when you find elements using your criteria then the function returns an HTML tag that contains navigation bar and search elements.

```html
<div class="panel-body">
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" onsubmit="return false;" role="search">
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" id="browse-country">
<option value="NONE">All Countries</option>
<option value="anguilla">Anguilla</option><option value="antigua-barbuda">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option><option value="aruba">Aruba</option><option value="bahamas">Bahamas</option><option value="barbados">Barbados</option><option value="belize">Belize</option><option value="bermuda">Bermuda</option><option value="british-vi">British Virgin Isles.</option><option value="cayman">Cayman Islands</option><option value="cuba">Cuba</option><option value="dominica">Dominica</option><option value="dominican-republic">Dominican Republic</option><option value="grenada">Grenada</option><option value="guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option><option value="guyana">Guyana</option><option value="haiti">Haiti</option><option value="jamaica">Jamaica</option><option value="martinique">Martinique</option><option value="montserrat">Montserrat</option><option value="netherland-antilles">Netherland Antilles</option><option value="puerto-rico">Puerto Rico</option><option value="st-lucia">St. Lucia</option><option value="kitts-nevis">St. Kitts &amp; Nevis</option><option value="st-vincent">St. Vincent</option><option value="st-martin">St. Martin/Maarten</option><option value="suriname">Suriname</option><option value="trinidad-tobago">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option><option value="turks-caicos">Turks &amp; Caicos</option><option value="us-vi">US Virgin Islands</option><option value="venezuela">Venezuela</option> </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" id="browse-category">
<option value="NONE">All Categories</option>
<option value="large-up">Large up</option><option value="shout-out">Shout out</option><option value="anatomy">Anatomy</option><option value="animal">Animal</option><option value="bingy">Bingy</option><option value="bird">Bird</option><option value="clothes">Clothes</option><option value="dance">Dance</option><option value="derogatory">Derogatory</option><option value="family">Family</option><option value="folklore">Folklore</option><option value="food">Food</option><option value="fruit">Fruit</option><option value="game">Game</option><option value="insect">Insect</option><option value="money">Money</option><option value="music">Music</option><option value="mythology">Mythology</option><option value="national-symbol">National symbol</option><option value="people">People</option><option value="person">Person</option><option value="pg">Pg</option><option value="place">Place</option><option value="plant">Plant</option><option value="plants">Plants</option><option value="pq">Pq</option><option value="profanity">Profanity</option><option value="proverb">Proverb</option><option value="quality">Quality</option><option value="religion">Religion</option><option value="river">River</option><option value="sexual">Sexual</option><option value="sickness">Sickness</option><option value="similie">Similie</option><option value="superstition">Superstition</option><option value="trinidad">Trinidad</option><option value="trinidadandtobago">Trinidadandtobago</option><option value="trinidadcreole">Trinidadcreole</option><option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option><option value="weapon">Weapon</option> </select>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="browseBtn">Browse</button>
</form>
</div>
```

This will AttributeError. You can avoid this error by using a try-except block

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(capture, 'lxml')
for words in soup.find_all('div', class_= 'panel-body'):
    extracted = words.find('h4') 
    if extracted not in results:
        try:
            results.append(extracted.text)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

You can also skip first element by using `soup.find_all('div', class_= 'panel-body')[2: ]`

- There is also a need to double check your if statement. In your statement you are checking for an HTML element in results list rather than its text. So you might end up having duplicates. You can rewrite your if statement as:

  extracted = words.find('h4').text
  if extracted not in results:
  results.append(extracted)

or use a set to remove duplicates

```
results = set(results)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests


capture = requests.get('http://wiwords.com/dictionary/').text
#print(capture)
results = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(capture, 'lxml')
for words in soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'panel-pody'}):
    extracted = words.find_all('h4') # Line that causes the error
    if extracted not in results:
        results.append(extracted.text)
```

can you try to run your code like this